# GRUB error while trying to run fully installed Ubuntu 12.04 from SSD

Tags: bootloader, ssd, windows-xp, bios, grubrescue

Due to my laptop having a RAM problem, I removed its SSD(which contains an Ubuntu 12.04 installation, with my personal data) and attempted to boot it from my old P4 machine lying around. This P4 machine has Windows XP installed on its drive.

So what I did was:

1. I disconnected the hard drive of the P4 machine.
2. I connected the SSD to the USB port via an adapter, and configured the (c2001) BIOS to boot from the SSD.

I am then presented with a GRUB rescue prompt. This is the first time seeing the GRUB prompt and I have no idea what commands to use to even poke around.

My first guess is that the problem is with the bootloader as I'm assuming the BIOS would have to load the bootloader in order to display the grub prompt in the first place. However beyond that I'm not sure what to make of this.

Anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: A BIOS from 2001 can boot from USB? That's odd. Anyway, if that's not the source of the problem, try the [Grub troubleshooting wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this post while looking for a solution to a problem I had after deleting a linux partition on a dual boot (xp-linux mint 9) netbook. I got the grub rescue prompt as well and I could solve my problem by running boot-repair from a live usb. You might want to try it to see if it works for you as well.

see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair